# Extract items from list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a column named 'Department' with a string of text that looks like:
n 1, Sociology / n 2, Genetics / n 3, Math ..etc.

I'm trying to extract the department names using a LIKE or If, Then Statement based on the number 1, 2, 3 etc. I'm relatively new to MySQL so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't put delimited data in columns. Again: don't put delimited data in columns. Once more: **don't put delimited data in columns.**

Comment: Unfortunately it's a database that was built sometime ago and this is how it's stored.

Comment: @Poohbreezy is it used by many seperate applications? If not, now may be a time to refactor/restructure a little - if you have the departments in a seperate table with an n:m linking table between the two, then the answer to your question becomes trivial.  If that is not an option, then I suggest reading up on FIND_IN_SET() string function, i.e. `FIND_IN_SET(col,'value')`

Comment: How do you want the final data set to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain I get the exact nature of your source column data.

If you're saying a single column in your example contains that list of departments delimited by slashes and you want to extract a single department given a known number it could be done something like this

```
select trim(substring_index(substring_index(column_name,'n 2,', -1),'/',1)) from mytable where <your criteria>;
```

ex.

```
> select trim(substring_index(substring_index( 'n 1, Sociology / n 2, Genetics / n 3, Math','n 2,',-1),'/',1)) as 'Department';
+------------+
| Department |
+------------+
| Genetics   |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I personally try to avoid doing parsing of blobs in mysql itself and delegate that code, but if for what ever reason you need to that may help (pending my correct interpretation of requirements).

The biggest problem to parsing "semi structured" data like this, whether in SQL or the application level is going to be when one of your delimiters is used as an unescaped literal value.  e.g. a slash being using as a delimiter and actual department name